# Как перехватывать ajax запросы?

Tags: angular, angular7

у меня есть httpInterceptor  и он отлично работает для httpClient  запросов, как создать перехватчик  ajax запросов в angular 7 ?

Comment: вопрос непонятен, что такое httpClient запросы и ajax? какая между ними разница? httpClient создает не ajax запросы? если нет - то какие же?

Comment: httpClient  это класс из angular,  а  ajax  из js . Я использую  фреймворк devextreme для таблиц, там используется ajax  запросы, мне нужно их перехватывать.

Comment: мне нужно перехватывать типа xhr  запросы)

Comment: это невозможно, для этого и придуман `HttpClient`, в `devextreme` же есть компоненты angular

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T661619/httpinterceptor-not-working-with-angular-6-using-createstore-and-datasource